# Failure to compile when enabling OpenGL debug output

Tags: c++, opengl, virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sdl-2

I'm trying to debug an C++ SDL2/OpenGL application (Globulation 2) in VirtualBox (openSUSE guest, Windows 10 host) and added the following code from learnopengl debugging tutorial to enable OpenGL debug output.

The reason I'm trying to enable debug output is there was a invalid operation error (0x502) returned by `glGetError` when I was running the program under gdb in VirtualBox and ran the command `print (const char*)glGetError()`, and I wanted OpenGL to tell me which OpenGL call caused the error.

```
void APIENTRY glDebugOutput(GLenum source, 
                            GLenum type, 
                            unsigned int id, 
                            GLenum severity, 
                            GLsizei length, 
                            const char *message, 
                            const void *userParam)
{
    // ignore non-significant error/warning codes
    if(id == 131169 || id == 131185 || id == 131218 || id == 131204) return; 

    std::cout << "---------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Debug message (" << id << "): " <<  message << std::endl;

    switch (source)
    {
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API:             std::cout << "Source: API"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_WINDOW_SYSTEM:   std::cout << "Source: Window System"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_SHADER_COMPILER: std::cout << "Source: Shader Compiler"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_THIRD_PARTY:     std::cout << "Source: Third Party"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION:     std::cout << "Source: Application"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_OTHER:           std::cout << "Source: Other"; break;
    } std::cout << std::endl;

    switch (type)
    {
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR:               std::cout << "Type: Error"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_DEPRECATED_BEHAVIOR: std::cout << "Type: Deprecated Behaviour"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR:  std::cout << "Type: Undefined Behaviour"; break; 
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PORTABILITY:         std::cout << "Type: Portability"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PERFORMANCE:         std::cout << "Type: Performance"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_MARKER:              std::cout << "Type: Marker"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PUSH_GROUP:          std::cout << "Type: Push Group"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_POP_GROUP:           std::cout << "Type: Pop Group"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER:               std::cout << "Type: Other"; break;
    } std::cout << std::endl;
    
    switch (severity)
    {
        case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH:         std::cout << "Severity: high"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_MEDIUM:       std::cout << "Severity: medium"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_LOW:          std::cout << "Severity: low"; break;
        case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_NOTIFICATION: std::cout << "Severity: notification"; break;
    } std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

and the following code in GraphicContext::setRes before creating the context:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_DEBUG_FLAG);
```

and the following code just after creating the context:

```
int debugcontext; glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, &debugcontext);
if (debugcontext & GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_DEBUG_BIT)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS); 
    glDebugMessageCallback(glDebugOutput, nullptr);
    glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, nullptr, GL_TRUE);
}
```

Here's how the window is created/resized:

```
bool GraphicContext::setRes(int w, int h, Uint32 flags)
    {
        // check dimension
        if (minW && (w < minW))
        {
            if (verbose)
                fprintf(stderr, "Toolkit : Screen width %d is too small, set to min %d\n", w, minW);
            w = minW;
        }
        if (minH && (h < minH))
        {
            if (verbose)
                fprintf(stderr, "Toolkit : Screen height %d is too small, set to min %d\n", h, minH);
            h = minH;
        }

        // set flags
        optionFlags = flags;
        Uint32 sdlFlags = 0;
        if (flags & FULLSCREEN)
            sdlFlags |= SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
        // FIXME: window resize is broken
        if (flags & RESIZABLE)
            sdlFlags |= SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE;
        #ifdef HAVE_OPENGL
        if (flags & USEGPU)
        {
            SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
            SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_DEBUG_FLAG);
            sdlFlags |= SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL;
        }
        #else
        // remove GL from options
        optionFlags &= ~USEGPU;
        #endif

        // if window exists, resize it
        if (window) {
            SDL_SetWindowSize(window, w, h);
            sdlsurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
#ifdef HAVE_OPENGL
            if (flags & USEGPU)
            {
                // https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62691/opengl-resize-problem
                glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
                glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                glLoadIdentity();
                glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
                glLoadIdentity();
            }
#endif
            setClipRect(0, 0, w, h);
            nextFrame();
            //screen->dispatchPaint();
        }
        else {
            // create the new window and the surface
            window = SDL_CreateWindow(windowTitle.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, w, h, sdlFlags);
        }
        sdlsurface = window != nullptr ? SDL_GetWindowSurface(window) : nullptr;

        // check surface
        if (!sdlsurface)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Toolkit : can't set screen to %dx%d at 32 bpp\n", w, h);
            fprintf(stderr, "Toolkit : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            _gc = this;
            // enable GL context
            if (flags & USEGPU && !context)
            {
                context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
                SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, context);
                int debugcontext; glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, &debugcontext);
                if (debugcontext & GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_DEBUG_BIT)
                {
                        glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
                    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS); 
                    glDebugMessageCallback(glDebugOutput, nullptr);
                    glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, nullptr, GL_TRUE);
                } 
            }
            // set _glFormat
            if ((optionFlags & USEGPU) && (_gc->sdlsurface->format->BitsPerPixel != 32))
            {
                _glFormat.palette = NULL;
                _glFormat.BitsPerPixel = 32;
                _glFormat.BytesPerPixel = 4;
                #if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
                _glFormat.Rmask = 0x000000ff;
                _glFormat.Rshift = 0;
                _glFormat.Gmask = 0x0000ff00;
                _glFormat.Gshift = 8;
                _glFormat.Bmask = 0x00ff0000;
                _glFormat.Bshift = 16;
                #else
                _glFormat.Rmask = 0x00ff0000;
                _glFormat.Rshift = 16;
                _glFormat.Gmask = 0x0000ff00;
                _glFormat.Gshift = 8;
                _glFormat.Bmask = 0x000000ff;
                _glFormat.Bshift = 0;
                #endif
                _glFormat.Amask = 0xff000000;
                _glFormat.Ashift = 24;
                _glFormat.Rloss = 0;
                _glFormat.Gloss = 0;
                _glFormat.Bloss = 0;
                _glFormat.Aloss = 0;
                //_glFormat.colorkey = 0;
                //_glFormat.alpha = 255;
                //_glFormat = *SDL_AllocFormat(32, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff, 0xff000000);
            }
            else
            {
                memcpy(&_glFormat, _gc->sdlsurface->format, sizeof(SDL_PixelFormat));
                unsigned alphaPos(24);
                if ((_glFormat.Rshift == 24) || (_glFormat.Gshift == 24) || (_glFormat.Bshift == 24))
                    alphaPos = 0;
                _glFormat.Amask = 0xff << alphaPos;
                _glFormat.Ashift = alphaPos;
                _glFormat.Aloss = 0;
            }

            #ifdef HAVE_OPENGL
            if (optionFlags & USEGPU)
                glState.checkExtensions();
            #endif // HAVE_OPENGL

            // setup title and icon
            if (!appIcon.empty())
            {
                SDL_Surface *iconSurface = IMG_Load(appIcon.c_str());
                SDL_SetWindowIcon(window, iconSurface);
                SDL_FreeSurface(iconSurface);
            }

            setClipRect();
            if (flags & CUSTOMCURSOR)
            {
                // disable system cursor
                SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);
                // load custom cursors
                cursorManager.load();
            }
            else
                SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_ENABLE);

            if (verbose)
                fprintf(stderr,
                    (flags & FULLSCREEN)
                    ?"Toolkit : Screen set to %dx%d at 32 bpp in fullscreen\n"
                    :"Toolkit : Screen set to %dx%d at 32 bpp in window\n",
                    w, h);

            #ifdef HAVE_OPENGL
            if (optionFlags & USEGPU)
            {
                gluOrtho2D(0, w, h, 0);
                glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
                glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
                glState.doTexture(true);
                glState.blendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            }
            #endif

            return true;
        }
    }
```

but it fails to compile in Windows Subsystem for Linux:

```
> scons -j6 --portaudio=true
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking whether the C compiler works... (cached) yes
Checking whether the C++ compiler works... (cached) yes
Checking for C library SDL2... (cached) yes
Checking for C library SDL2_ttf... (cached) yes
Checking for C library SDL2_image... (cached) yes
Checking for C library SDL2_net... (cached) yes
Checking for C library speex... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file speex/speex.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C library vorbisfile... (cached) yes
Checking for C library vorbis... (cached) yes
Checking for C library ogg... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file zlib.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C library z... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file regex.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C library boost_thread... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file boost/thread/thread.hpp... (cached) yes
Checking for C library boost_date_time... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file boost/shared_ptr.hpp... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file boost/tuple/tuple.hpp... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file boost/logic/tribool.hpp... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file boost/lexical_cast.hpp... (cached) yes
Checking for C library GL... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file GL/gl.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C library GLU... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file GL/glu.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C library fribidi... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file fribidi/fribidi.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C library portaudio... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file portaudio.h... (cached) yes
trying to use portaudio
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/libgag/src/GraphicContext.o -c -g3 -O0 -Wall -fPIC -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_REENTRANT -Ilibgag/include -I. -Ilibusl/src -I/usr/include/SDL2 libgag/src/GraphicContext.cpp
libgag/src/GraphicContext.cpp: In member function 'virtual bool GAGCore::GraphicContext::setRes(int, int, Uint32)':
libgag/src/GraphicContext.cpp:2151:6: error: 'glDebugMessageCallback' was not declared in this scope
      glDebugMessageCallback(glDebugOutput, nullptr);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libgag/src/GraphicContext.cpp:2151:6: note: suggested alternative: 'gluTessCallback'
      glDebugMessageCallback(glDebugOutput, nullptr);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      gluTessCallback
libgag/src/GraphicContext.cpp:2152:6: error: 'glDebugMessageControl' was not declared in this scope
      glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, nullptr, GL_TRUE);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
scons: *** [build/libgag/src/GraphicContext.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

The output of `glxinfo | grep version` in VirtualBox is:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.2.4
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.2.a
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.2.4
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
```

How do I make the program compile? It compiled just fine before I added the above code. I'm thinking the compilation error might be because the OpenGL version is too low but the core profile is 4.5 so that should be high enough, right?

If the OpenGL version is actually too low, I guess I could sprinkle `glCheckError` calls (the other method of debugging in the learnopengl article) in the code, or use apitrace.

I tried compiling in VirtualBox itself and the same error shows up.

WSL distro is openSUSE 15.2.

my G++ version in WSL is:

```
g++ (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

VirtualBox is version 6.1.26. Guest is openSUSE 15.3; Host is Windows 10 Home 20H2 19042.1110.

SCons is version:

```
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    SCons: v4.0.1.c289977f8b34786ab6c334311e232886da7e8df1, 2020-07-17 01:50:03, by bdbaddog on ProDog2020
    SCons path: ['/mnt/d/Linux_home/nathan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2020 The SCons Foundation
```

Comment: By the looks of it, virtual box just doesn't support the required API version. You *might* be able to extract a function pointer to glDebugMessageCallback via glXGetProcAddress, but if that fails, you're out of luck I suspect?

Comment: When you say "\[`SDL_GL_SetAttribute()`\] before creating the context" do you mean "before creating the window + `SDL_GL_CreateContext()`" (correct) or "after creating the window but before `SDL_GL_CreateContext()`" (incorrect)?  `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` only affects the next `SDL_CreateWindow()` call, calling it after has no effect.

Comment: @genpfault I'm not sure how that's going to help with the function not being in the header.

Comment: The `SDL_GL_SetAttribute` call happens in the OpenGL path (there's also a software path) before either resizing (if window exists) or creating the window (if there's no window yet). so it gets called both before and after window creation.

Comment: You could also drop a [`MESA_DEBUG=1` or `MESA_DEBUG=context`](https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html) envvar before running the program to get similar info on stderr.

Comment: I'd generate an OpenGL 2.1 [GLAD](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad) & bodge that into the buildsystem if you really need/want the debug callback, [manual extension wrangling](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_GetProcAddress) is kinda tedious.

Comment: Presumably, the gl.h header provided in your system does not contain OpenGL 4.3 core declarations. Your best bet is probably to ignore it entirely and instead use the header provided by an external loader like [glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/)

Comment: I solved the compilation error by using SDL_GL_GetProcAddress which was linked to in @genpfault's comment. However the OpenGL error I was getting seems to have disappeared. Also I tried `MESA_DEBUG=1` and `MESA_DEBUG=context`  before the executable name and it doesn't seem to change the output; I get ALSA errors, libpng errors, and jack errors but no OpenGL error messages.